# Table view inside a table view 

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uitableview

In my app i am having a table view in which i am having buttons in which images are shown .Now what i want is that when i click on any image(button).then another table view has to be shown inside the first table view.Then i need to click on the images present in the second table view .How can i achieve that .Is it possible to create a table view inside other table view or i is there any other solution like creating a view and then adding images inside it.Please help.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Christy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but Apple [advises not putting a `UITableView` inside another `UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) (it makes touch tracking and behavior significantly more complex).

The best solution depends on your exact situation, but if the sub-view contains a lot of data, you can move it off into it's own modal view, or you can create a static or semi-static view that is embedded inside your `UITableViewCell` when that cell is selected.